# Find the smallest positive missing number in unsorted array

Tags: kdb

Please help me to write a function to find smallest positive number *not* in the list. I tried below however I'm not able to complete the solution.

```
Sample data
list: 2 9 -10 5 3 1 11 -1 7        /output:4
list2: -10 4 -4 2 15 13 6 8 -1     /Output: 1
list3: 1 1 0 18 1 -12 -6 18 21    /Output: 2


q)list: 2 9 -10 5 3 1 11 -1 7   
q)l where (signum l:asc list) <> -1
1 2 3 5 7 9 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach

```
q){min(1+0|x)except x}1 1 0 18 1 -12 -6 18 21
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Original solution based on first reading of the question

```
q){min x where 0<x}[2 9 -10 5 3 1 11 -1 7]
1
q){min x where 0<x}[-10 4 -4 2 15 13 6 8 -1]
2
q){min x where 0<x}[1 1 0 18 1 -12 -6 18 21]
1
```

**EDIT**:

Alternative solution based on comments

```
q){1+min where s<>1+til count s:asc x where 0<x}[2 9 -10 5 3 1 11 -1 7]
4
q){1+min where s<>1+til count s:asc x where 0<x}[-10 4 -4 2 15 13 6 8 -1]
1
q){1+min where s<>1+til count s:asc x where 0<x}[1 1 0 18 1 -12 -6 18 21]
2
```

Comment: He wants the smallest possible "missing" positive number, i.e. what isn't in the list, or the first gap in the positive numbers.  What yours does is output the smallest present positive number.

Comment: I should get 4 for list: 2 9 -10 5 3 1 11 -1 7 not 1. Please help to review your solution.

Comment: Ah, I've added a different solution in my edit